# How prove $x_{1},y_{1},z_{1}$ is also $x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$ solution

Tags: number-theory, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

> let $x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}$ such $$(x^2_{0}+y^2_{0}-z^2_{0})(x^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-y^2_{0})(y^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-x^2_{0})\neq 0$$ if $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ is the equation solution
> $$x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)\tag{1}$$
> then
> $$(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$$ is also equation (1) solution,where
> $$x_{1}=\dfrac{1}{x^2_{0}+y^2_{0}-z^2_{0}},y_{1}=\dfrac{1}{x^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-y^2_{0}},z_{1}=\dfrac{1}{y^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-x^2_{0}}$$

My some idea: since
$$x^3_{0}+y^3_{0}+z^3_{0}=(x_{0}+y_{0})(y_{0}+z_{0})(x_{0}+z_{0})$$
and$$(x^2_{0}+y^2_{0}-z^2_{0})(x^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-y^2_{0})(y^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-x^2_{0})\neq 0$$
and we must prove
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2_{0}+y^2_{0}-z^2_{0}}\right)^3+\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-y^2_{0}}\right)^3+\left(\dfrac{1}{y^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-x^2_{0}}\right)^3=\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2_{0}+y^2_{0}-z^2_{0}}+\dfrac{1}{x^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-y^2_{0}}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-y^2_{0}}+\dfrac{1}{y^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-x^2_{0}}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{y^2_{0}+z^2_{0}-x^2_{0}}+\dfrac{1}{x^2_{0}+y^2_{0}-z^2_{0}}\right)$$
**Question 1**:

I think this idea will ugly,and I think this problem have other simple methods.

**Question 2:**  How find this form with the  $x_{1},y_{1},z_{1}$   Thank you

The follow figure is my frends sent to me.

[image]

Comment: Do you know for sure that this is true? Or is this a conjecture?

Comment: The RHS of your equation is $2xyz+\sum a^2b$, where the sum ranges over $a\neq b\in\{x, y, z\}$; dividing this by $x^2y^2z^2$ yields $2x^{-1}y^{-1}z^{-1}+\sum c^2d$, where this time the sum ranges over $c\neq d\in\{x^{-1},y^{-1},z^{-1}\}$ - in other words, calling the RHS $f(x,y,z)$ then $f(x,y,z) = x^2y^2z^2 f(x^{-1}, y^{-1}, z^{-1})$ (there may be a more obvious way to see this).  Maybe you can make use of that symmetry somehow?

Comment: @Blue,I think this is true.

Comment: "I think this is true." As I've suggested before, you need to be more clear about whether the questions you ask are known to be true. (Many a question of yours that I recall has turned-out to be a conjecture ... sometimes a false one.) It's rude to potential answerers to ask them to prove something that might be unprovable, so please give fair warning when this might be the case. Also, I notice that you have accepted very few answers lately. That's *even more rude* to *actual* answerers who have taken time to help you.

Comment: @math110 Could you translate the figure?.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $(x, y, z)=(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is a solution to $x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$, and $x_0^2+y_0^2-z_0^2, x_0^2+z_0^2-y_0^2, y_0^2+z_0^2-x_0^2 \not =0$.

---

If any of $x_0, y_0, z_0=0$, WLOG assume $z_0=0$. Then 
$$x_0^3+y_0^3=(x_0+y_0)x_0y_0$$ 
$$(x_0+y_0)(x_0^2-x_0y_0+y_0^2)=(x_0+y_0)x_0y_0$$ 
$$(x_0+y_0)(x_0-y_0)^2=0$$
$$x_0= \pm y_0$$
$$x_0^2+z_0^2-y_0^2=x_0^2+0-x_0^2=0$$
a contradiction.

Thus $x_0, y_0, z_0 \not =0$.

---

If $x_0+y_0+z_0=0$, then note 
$$-x_0y_0z_0=(-x_0)(-y_0)(-z_0)=(y_0+z_0)(x_0+z_0)(x_0+y_0)=x_0^3+y_0^3+z_0^3=3x_0y_0z_0+(x_0+y_0+z_0)(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2-x_0y_0-x_0z_0-y_0z_0)=3x_0y_0z_0$$

so at least one of $x_0, y_0, z_0$ is $0$, so we get a contradiction by above.

Thus $x_0+y_0+z_0 \not =0$.

---

Notice that 
\begin{align}
&(x_0+y_0-z_0)(x_0^2+y_0^2-z_0^2)\\
& =x_0^3+y_0^3+z_0^3+x_0y_0^2+x_0^2y_0^2-x_0z_0^2-x_0^2z_0-y_0z_0^2-y_0^2z_0 \\
&=(x_0+y_0)(x_0+z_0)(y_0+z_0)+x_0y_0^2+x_0^2y_0^2-x_0z_0^2-x_0^2z_0-y_0z_0^2-y_0^2z_0\\
&=2x_0y_0^2+2x_0^2y_0+2x_0y_0z_0\\
&=2x_0y_0(x_0+y_0+z_0)
\end{align}

Thus $$z_0(x_0+y_0-z_0)=\frac{2x_0y_0z_0(x_0+y_0+z_0)}{x_0^2+y_0^2-z_0^2}=2x_0y_0z_0(x_0+y_0+z_0)x_1$$

Similarly

$$y_0(x_0+z_0-y_0)=2x_0y_0z_0(x_0+y_0+z_0)y_1$$
$$x_0(y_0+z_0-x_0)=2x_0y_0z_0(x_0+y_0+z_0)z_1$$

Define $\lambda=2x_0y_0z_0(x_0+y_0+z_0) \not =0$ by above.
Define $$a=z(x+y-z), b=y(x+z-y), c=x(y+z-x)$$
We get the corresponding $$a_0=z_0(x_0+y_0-z_0)=\lambda x_1, b_0=y_0(x_0+z_0-y_0)=\lambda y_1, c_0=x_0(y_0+z_0-x_0)=\lambda z_1$$

Notice that $(x, y, z)=(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ is a solution to $x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$ if and only if $(x, y, z)=(a_0, b_0, c_0)=\lambda (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ is a solution. (Since $\lambda \not =0$)

It thus suffices to prove $a_0^3+b_0^3+c_0^3=(a_0+b_0)(a_0+c_0)(b_0+c_0)$.

---

Now, write 
$P(x, y, z)=a^3+b^3+c^3-(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$ which is easily seen to be a degree $6$ homogeneous and symmetric polynomial in $x, y, z$.

Observe that if $x+y-z=0$, then $a=z(x+y-z)=0$, $b=y(x+z-y)=y(x+(x+y)-y)=2xy$, $c=x(y+z-x)=x(y+(x+y)-y)=2xy$, so $P(x, y, z)=0^3+(2xy)^3+(2xy)^3-(2xy)(2xy)(4xy)=0$. This holds for any $x, y, z$ s.t. $x+y-z=0$, so we must have $x+y-z$ as a factor of $P$.

By symmetry we may then write $$P(x, y, z)=(x+y-z)(x+z-y)(y+z-x)Q(x, y, z)$$ where $Q$ is a degree 3 homogeneous and symmetric polynomial in $x, y, z$.

By symmetry, we have $$Q(x, y, z)=\alpha(x^3+y^3+z^3)+\beta(x^2y+y^2x+x^2z+z^2x+y^2z+z^2y)+\gamma xyz$$

for some constants $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

When $(x, y, z)=(1, 0, 0)$, we get $(a, b, c)=(0, 0, -1)$, so
$$-1=0^3+0^3+(-1)^3-(0)(-1)(-1)=P(1, 0, 0)=-Q(1, 0, 0)=-\alpha$$

Thus $\alpha=1$.

When $(x, y, z)=(1, 2, 0)$, we get $(a, b, c)=(0, -2, 1)$, so
\begin{align}
-9=0^3+(-2)^3+1^3-(-2)(1)(-1)=P(1, 2, 0)&=(3)(-1)(1)Q(1, 2, 0)\\
&=-3*(9\alpha+6\beta)\\
&=-27-18\beta
\end{align}

Thus $\beta=-1$.

When $(x, y, z)=(1, 1, 1)$, we get $(a, b, c)=(1, 1, 1)$, so
$$-5=1^3+1^3+1^3-(2)(2)(2)=P(1, -1, 0)=Q(1, 1, 1)=3\alpha+6\beta+\gamma=3-6+\gamma$$

Thus $\gamma=-2$.

We get 
\begin{align}
Q(x, y, z)&=x^3+y^3+z^3-[(x^2y+y^2x+x^2z+z^2x+y^2z+z^2y)+2xyz)\\
&=x^3+y^3+z^3-(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)
\end{align}

Thus 
\begin{align}
&a^3+b^3+c^3-(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\\
&=P(x, y, z)\\
&=(x+y-z)(x+z-y)(y+z-x)(x^3+y^3+z^3-(x+y)(x+z)(y+z))
\end{align}

Thus 
\begin{align}
&a_0^3+b_0^3+c_0^3-(a_0+b_0)(a_0+c_0)(b_0+c_0)\\
&=P(x_0, y_0, z_0)\\
&=(x_0+y_0-z_0)(x_0+z_0-y_0)(y_0+z_0-x_0)(x_0^3+y_0^3+z_0^3-(x_0+y_0)(x_0+z_0)(y_0+z_0)) \\
&=0
\end{align}

and we are done.

---

N.B. Alternatively, use a computer program to help factorise $P(x, y, z)$ in under a minute.